# ASP.NET MVC membership login for different domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, sqlmembershipprovider

I am using one membership database for different domain. When I login in one domain, I want to automatically also perform a login for different domain in same browser.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. Due to JavaScript Security, one cannot reads cookie set by others.

***For example***, www.mycompany.com cannot read cookie set by www.yoursite.com.

However, if those two websites are in different sub-domains, you can configure them to share the same cookie.

For example,

- one.mycompany.com
- two.mycompany.com

***Note:*** ASP.Net offers Token Based Authentication, but you cannot use it with ASP.Net Membership.